# Initializr service call failed, returned Bad Request: Unknown dependency 'rest'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to replicate [this Spring Initializr setup](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.7.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=explorecali&name=explorecali&description=Explore%20California%20Microservice&packageName=com.example.explorecali&dependencies=web,data-rest,h2,data-jpa) using the `spring init` cli.

However, the command returns the following error message whenever I try to add 'rest' as a dependency i.e. Rest Repositories that expose Spring Data repositories over REST.

```
Initializr service call failed using 'https://start.spring.io' - service returned Bad Request: 'Unknown dependency 'rest' check project metadata'
```

Here is the command I'm running:

```bash
spring init --build=maven \
--java-version=11 \
--artifact=explorecali \
--package-name=com.example.ec \
--name=explorecali \
--description="Explore California Microservice" \
--dependencies=web,h2,jpa,rest \
--packaging=jar \
sample-app.zip
```

If `rest` isn't the correct dependency name, what is? Moreover, how can one list the available dependencies from the command line to get their correct names.

Comment: There isn't any documentation for the `init` subcommand through `spring init --help` and `spring init --help` by itself is too general.

Comment: is `rest` in your `pom` file?

Comment: @BenjaminW `rest` isn't in my pom if I try to create it using the `spring init` cli (because of the error mentioned above) However, if I use the web interface, https://start.spring.io/, to select dependencies, rest is present as a dependency with artifact id `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` and group id `org.springframework.boot`.

Comment: Add this to your pom maybe.  ` <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-rest -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
`

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks for the help, but the issue isn't how I can add the dependency manually to my pomfile, but how I can get `spring init` to do this step for me. The idea is that, instead of pointing a dev to the site and telling them to click-through the desired dependencies, or to create their own project and pom file, I can just give them the `spring init` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the url of the link you posted, it has the dependency names listed out.

```
https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.7.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=explorecali&name=explorecali&description=Explore%20California%20Microservice&packageName=com.example.explorecali&dependencies=web,data-rest,h2,data-jpa
```

The final portion of the url, `dependencies=web,data-rest,h2,data-jpa`, shows us that the Rest Repositories are added with `data-rest`, not rest.
Spring Data JPA is added with `data-jpa`, not `jpa`.

Hope this helps.